# Showing an image in C Ubuntu

Tags: c, linux, image, ubuntu, compression

I'm new in Linux (Ubuntu) and I have to do a code in C that have to uncompress an image, print the size of the image and show the image. 
I have to use zcat, wc (wc -c) and xview (xview stdin).
This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>


int PID;
int PIPE1[2];

void zcat(char INPUT[]) 
{
   dup2(PIPE1[1],STDOUT_FILENO);
   close(PIPE1[0]);
   close(PIPE1[1]);
   execlp("zcat","zcat",INPUT,NULL);
   perror("\nzcat malo\n");
   exit(0);
}

void show_image() 
{     
   dup2(PIPE1[0],STDIN_FILENO);
   close(PIPE1[0]);
   close(PIPE1[1]);
   execlp("xview","xview","stdin",NULL);
   perror("\nxview malo\n");
   exit(0);
}

void image_size() 
{     
   dup2(PIPE1[0], STDIN_FILENO);
   close(PIPE1[0]); 
   close(PIPE1[1]);
   execlp("wc","wc","-c",NULL);
   perror("\nwc error\n");
   exit(0);
}

void xview(char INPUT[])
{
   if(pipe(PIPE1)==-1) 
   {
      perror("\npipe1 malo\n");
      exit(1);
   }
   if((PID=fork())==-1)
   {
        perror("\nfork1 error\n");
        exit(1);
   }
   else if(PID==0)  zcat(INPUT);
   if((PID=fork())==-1) 
   {
        perror("\nfork2 error\n");
        exit(1);
   } 
   else if(PID==0) show_image();
   close(PIPE1[0]);
   close(PIPE1[1]);
}


void wc(char INPUT[])
{
    if(pipe(PIPE1)==-1) 
    {
        perror("\npipe1 malo\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if((PID=fork())==-1) 
    {
        perror("\nfork1 error\n");
        exit(1);
    } 
    else if(PID==0) zcat(INPUT);
    if((PID=fork())==-1) 
    {
        perror("\nfork2 error\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if(PID==0) image_size();
    close(PIPE1[0]);
    close(PIPE1[1]);
}



void main() 
{
   char INPUT[20];
   scanf("%s",INPUT);
   xview(INPUT);
   wc(INPUT);
}
```

In INPUT I have to put the name of the file that contains the image (image.png). imagelinux.png.gz
When I run this in the terminal the program shows "xview malo" : No such file or directory
and prints the image size in bytes.
It doesn't showw the image :C
HELP!

Comment: If you type `xview` at the command line does it open xview?

Comment: there seems to be a logic error between the call to `zlib` and the next line, as it is unclear about which process is running and we can expect `zlib` to return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install xview with `sudo apt-get install xloadimage` and your program will work.